# How to use require with javascript browser

Tags: javascript, browserify

I am using react and need to use modules, hence I have to use `require`.

I found a way to use require in JS browser which is **BROWSERIFY**.

I installed browserify and diffie-hellman(module I want to use) by npm.

**dh.js**

```js
var crypto = require('diffie-hellman/browser');
```

After executing the following command

```
browserify dh.js -o bundle.js
```

The bundle file has been created with the commands inside.

now, how to import this bundle.js inside the react app to use the module? I tried to use

import "bundle.js"

but the compiler shows me those errors inside the bundle

> Line 6240:82:   Unexpected use of 'self'
> no-restricted-globals   Line 6240:105:  Unexpected use of 'self'
> no-restricted-globals

shall I import bundle or dh instead?
sorry it's my first time I use browserify.

Comment: Is your React code not colocated? how do you compile your react code?

Comment: It's my first time to use browserify, I have the bundle file after browserify process ,but I don't know how to use the functions inside the bundle ,I tried import but it doesn't work

Comment: What is error did you get when you have tried to import the `dh.js` file?

Comment: There is no need to bundle just import like this: 
```
import './name'
```

Comment: @NicoVignola ,The page continues to load uselessly, like an endless loop

Comment: @MatinZD,I tried but the page continues to load uselessly

Comment: If you open the developer tools you should see an error message

Comment: @NicoVignola ,ok I fixed the errors now it works but how to use this module,I mean we were using var c = require("module"),then we use this c like c.function but here what should i do to use this function. what I did until now was importing "./dh" I tried to use function from this module like createDiffieHellman but it doesn't work... I really appreciate your help

Comment: What is `dh.js` containing? Is it only the line you posted (`var crypto = require('diffie-hellman/browser');`)? Or did you add more export(s) to it?

Comment: I tried to add function which used this module in dh.js with the export of this fucntion but   The page continues to load uselessly, like an endless loop  it shows me this expression "Waiting for update signal from WDS... " after a while it shows me that "The development server has disconnected."...if I tried to use function without using module. normal function contains console.log it works correctly